# Game center photo reset several minutes in sand box?

Tags: ios, photo, center

I encounter a problem: The game center photo reset automatically several minutes in sandbox. Does anyone know this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the sandbox server doesn't remember your photos. Your device will cache your photo locally immediately after you set it, but the next time it requests the photo from Game Center it'll be back to one of the default sandbox photos (silhouette with red, green, yellow, or blue text).

Just one of the many, many, many, many, many sucky things about Game Center I'm afraid :(